# Convert array of hashes to single hash with values as keys

Tags: ruby

Given a source array of hashes:

```
[{:country=>'england', :cost=>12.34}, {:country=>'scotland', :cost=>56.78}]
```

Is there a neat Ruby one-liner for converting it to a single hash, where the values for the `:country` key in the original hash (guaranteed to be unique) become keys in the new hash?

```
{:england=>12.34, :scotland=>56.78}
```

Comment: Presumably, values for `:country` are unique. It might have been better to have asked for `{"england"=>12.34, "scotland"=>56.78}` as the conversion of keys from strings to symbols is not central to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
countries.each_with_object({}) { |country, h| h[country[:country].to_sym] = country[:cost] }
 => {:england=>12.34, :scotland=>56.78}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [Enumerable#inject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```rb
countries.inject({}) { |hsh, element| hsh.merge!(element[:country].to_sym => element[:cost]) }
 => {:england=>12.34, :scotland=>56.78}
```

We initialise the accumulator as `{}`, and then we iterate over each of the elements of the initial array and add the new formatted element to the accumulator.

One point to add is that using `hsh.merge` or `hsh.merge!` would have the same effect for the output, given that `inject` will set the accumulator `hsh` as the return value from the block. However, using `merge!` is better when it comes to memory usage, given that `merge` will always generate a new Hash, whereas `merge!` will apply the merge over the same existing Hash.

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution is:

```rb
countries.map(&:values).to_h
 => {"england"=>12.34, "scotland"=>56.78}
```

Comment: This is a very brittle solution, as it relies on the order of key/value pairs in the hash. If `countries` is  `[{:country=>'england', :cost=>12.34}, {:cost=>56.78, :country=>'scotland'}]` then your solution returns `{"england"=>12.34, 56.78=>"scotland"}`

Comment: It will also fail if each hash contains anything other than two key/value pairs.